# C - Parent process waits indefinitely on forked child process running authopen

Tags: c, macos, pipe, exec, fork

I am trying to get my parent process to wait on a child fork that runs `authopen`, to write a file with elevated privileges. The `wait/waitpid` in the parent hangs indefinitely for the child process to terminate. I believe this is because `authopen` does not release the file until the program exits.

The file that `authopen` writes to is locked during the program's lifetime, such that the file can not be read from, can not be written to using another `authopen` process, and opening the file in e.g. vim does not show the content of the file until the program has exited.

First, I'd like to understand what's going on here. When `execl` completes, shouldn't it also release all resources?

Second, I'd like some pointers to a solution.

Below is a program that demonstrates the problem.

My platform is OSX.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int pip[2];

    if (pipe(pip) != 0) exit(1);    //error creating pipe

    pid_t processId;
    processId = fork();

    if (processId == -1) exit(1);    //pipe error

    if (processId == 0) {   //child process

        //close 'write end' of pipe
        close(pip[1]);

        //close stdin and duplicate the 'read end' of pipe to stdin
        close(0);
        dup(pip[0]);

        //run authopen
        const char * authopenPath = "/usr/libexec/authopen";

        execl(authopenPath, authopenPath, "-c","-w","/usr/local/authopenTest.txt",NULL);

        _exit(1);    //exec* does not return in case of success.
    }
    else {      //parent process

        //close 'read end' of pipe
        close(pip[0]);

        //write to 'write end' of pipe
        char * cstr = "write this to file...";
        write(pip[1], cstr, (strlen(cstr)));

        int status;
        //waitpid(0, &status, WNOHANG);     //this is ok, but doesn't block on child completing
        int p_id = wait(&status);           //PROBLEM: this hangs indefinitely. Why?
        if(p_id != -1)  {
            printf("Exit status %d\n", status);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After you `dup(pip[0])` you should `close(pip[0])`

Comment: But more importantly, the parent needs to close pip[1], since the child is probably blocking on a read from the pipe.

Comment: Yes, `authopen` doesn't exit until it receives EOF on its stdin.

Comment: Thank you both for the insight. @william Closing pip[1] in the parent did it. If you submit I can accept as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close the pipe after you have finished writing to it.  Otherwise, the reader continues to wait for more data.  eg:

```
write(pip[1], ...);
close(pip[1]);
wait(...);
```